# Authentication problem with my PPA

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, packaging

I created a package and uploaded it to my PPA. After it got built, I went to install it, but was faced with this message:

```
$ sudo apt-get install stackapplet
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  stackapplet
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.7kB of archives.
After this operation, 106kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  stackapplet
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

Why is it warning me about the packages not being verified?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by a missing PGP key in your APT keyring. You can add the key with the following command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 72D340A3
```

Of course you need to replace the key with your PPA key.

Also, the following command will add the key automatically:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name
```

After adding the key, you need to run apt-get update to download and verify the signature.

Comment: +1, BTW the exact command to add your ppa is shown right on the PPA  web page.

Comment: Perfect! One small little issue - the repository isn't showing up in the "Ubuntu Software Center".

Comment: @Pynt: I don't see it anywhere on the page...

Comment: @George: It's right there in bold https://edge.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/george-edison

Comment: @Pynt: All I see is the lines to add to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. I don't see any commands.

Comment: @George, oops my bad, it shows `ppa:george-edison55/george-edison` but not the `sudo add-apt-repository`. Although there is a `Read about installing` link there which explains all of this right there too. ;-)